# How to center an image?

Tags: support, images

Is it possible to show the image below centered instead of aligned to the left?

[image: test]

Comment: Closely related question (duplicate?): [How to center a figure in the post?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4296/how-to-center-a-figure-in-the-post). This is also somewhat related: [How to Post Pictures in an Array/Table, on MSE, with MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11053/how-to-post-pictures-in-an-array-table-on-mse-with-mathjax)

Comment: Please, just don't...

Comment: Ask the developers for *real* centering support. Maybe one of them will see this [meta-tag:support] tagged post.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2851) is the only [meta-tag:feature-request] I see that asks for centering support for images. Perhaps we need another.

Comment: I'm surprised this doesn't come up more often in the mathematical SE sites. I found my way here after posting this: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10037/when-did-cross-multiplication-enter-into-common-use

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**If You Really Must...**

The way I center an image is to put an appropriately sized `\hspace{}` before the image. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1055534), you can see

`Here is a plot of $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{(-1)^n}n$ showing the non-monotonicity:`

`$\hspace{3cm}$![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5eu5.png)`

which shows up as

> Here is a plot of $\displaystyle\frac1{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{(-1)^n}n$ showing the non-monotonicity:
>
> $\hspace{3cm}$[image]

Note that this only works in those forums that support MathJax (such as math.stackexchange.com).

---

As mentioned in a comment to the question, there is [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4297) by Zev Chonoles that suggests this method and HTML markup, using multiple `&nbsp;`s or spaces in a `<pre>...</pre>` block.

However, whether MathJax and `\hspace{}` or HTML and `&nbsp;`, these are both workarounds for a *real* centering method from the developers. In terms of editing posts if we should ever get a *real* centering method, using the simplest option seems the best.

---

**Centered: To Be or Not To Be...**

As Davide Cervone points out in comments, it is not friendly to the visually impaired to indent images using MathJax.  Some readers may add a confusing MathMode interlude where there is only whitespace (one might say that a good reader would skip these, but I imagine readers might lack this feature just as SE lacks image centering). So in the end, this means we should not attempt to center our images and [**ask SE to please provide image centering**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2851).

Furthermore, we should also fill in the "enter image description here" for our images, so that the readers can describe an image for the visually impaired.

Comment: One should not use MathJax to create "white-space."

Comment: @quid: thanks for your caveat. Do you have anything positive to suggest? Do you have an explanation of why, if the forum supports MathJax, one should not use it? It can't be an issue of portability, since our posts here are riddled with MathJax. It seems to me that a single, easily adjusted `\hspace{}` command is better than a bunch of `&nbsp;`s.

Comment: The main reason is that MathJax should best be used *for math only*, for semantic reasons. There are some other reasons too, but that one should be the clearest. Let me just reproduce the reply/confirmation I got recently from Davide Cervone, the lead developper of MathJax: "MathJax should be used only for mathematical content, not for adding white space, or italics, or colored text, or background colors, or line breaks in comments, or other display hacks, to textual (non-math) content."

Comment: For a positive suggestion: Have trust in the default layout; on average it is better and at least it is good enough. Or, what Najib Idrissi said, not sure if it qualifies as positive. Or, what Mariano said on the first linked post.  Do you know how much 3cm are relative to my screensize? The same applies to the &nbsp; due to the *brilliant* "centering" I can only see half the image there! The rest is "centered" right outside my screen. Let us just stop this kind of tinkering.

Comment: @quid: The same could be said of any workaround used to simulate features that we don't have otherwise. MathJax is a markup language, just like HTML; so the same argument can be made against using HTML for adding whitespace. I don't like using either of them, because they are not *actually* centering and are relying on the width of the page. Does that mean, without centering support from the SE developers, that we should simply have badly formatted images in posts?

Comment: It seems you have not seen my second comment. *Yes*, we should accept that format. Also, it does not seem quite correct to say that the same as for MathJax could be said for HTML. Roughly, MathJax is for math, while HTML is for hyper text in general, as indicated by the respective names.

Comment: We use what we are given. If I don't have a napkin, I will use a paper towel. Even though a napkin was designed for that purpose, I don't want to do without something there. If they are not given a real centering method, people will use what they can. I doubt people will stand on semantics and settle for left-justified images.

Comment: Analogies are always a bit complicated. So, you are of the opinion that in a library in need of a tissue or papertowel yet not having one, one is free to rip out some pages of some book and use them instead? You should not simply abuse a shared resource just because it might be convenient for you.

Comment: @robjohn: I've settled for left-justified images. ;-)

Comment: @quid: I'm sorry, was that *your* paper towel? I was suggesting using something that was available for me to use. A book in a library is not available for my use in that manner.

Comment: The entire point of my analogy is that you misuse something that is made available to you for a specific purpose, for a different one. MathJax is made available to you to typeset math, and it is *not* made available to you to create whitespace. You can do it, just as you can rip out the pages of a book that is made available to you to read it: and if you are discreet about it chances are noone will ever hold you responsible for it (in either case). Still it is a misuse.

Comment: @quid: I have searched the [MathJax Documentation pages](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/) and I have found nothing about this. Just because Davide has said something in a private message to you about the intended use of MathJax does not make use outside of those intentions "misuse". I agree that this is a workaround, and that in an ideal world, we would have image centering in the standard markup language. However, almost all programming relies on some workarounds for things that are not available, and this is a workaround.

Comment: @robjohn MathJax is only activated on those SE sites that have a need for displaying math (and closely related things). This clearly shows that it is made available here to you by SE *for this purpose.* It is *not* made available to you on AskDifferent, for instance, while you still might want to center an image there.

Comment: I did not want to cause the impression this was some official position of MJ, but you should be able to glance from the documentation that it is indeed designed for displaying math :-) And http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/17543/ plus comemnts talks about how it is desirable that semantics is improved and how it is worse with the type of behavior you promote.  It seems you think your personal estetic preferences (that btw make me not see an image on mobile) should trump this. I have not further interest in continuing this debate.

Comment: I'm sorry, @robjohn, but clearly the intended purpose of MathJax is to allow the formatting of mathematical formulae, and not to provide spacing to mimic center-alignment of other elements, nor to meet minimum character requirements in text fields `${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$`-style. As rendering MathJax is fairly intensive, it makes sense to consider such alternative uses _misuses_.

Comment: @quid So, I assume you think it's ok to use multiple `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Looks like `$\hskip x in$` works with mobile: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51525/geometry-or-topology-behind-the-impossible-staircase/51530#51530 http://i.stack.imgur.com/LHry6.png

Comment: @Wood given that I  wrote above 'The same applies to the &nbsp; due to the brilliant "centering" I can only see half the image there!' it is completely unclear to me how you can assume this. (In some ways  &nbsp;  is better in some ways it is worse. Your final observation does nothing to adress the main concern I put forward re usage of MJ.)

Comment: @Wood: I have never had a problem seeing the images on my iPhone in my posts using `\hspace{}` either. I don't think that viewing images on mobile devices is the problem; it is a semantic issue: MathJax was intended for the layout of mathematics. It is interesting that `\hskip` is even supported in MathJax since that was not intended for mathematical equations; `\hskip` is a TeX command for text layout, `\mskip` is the TeX command for math layout.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: I am not arguing that using MathJax for spacing other parts of a post is the right thing to do. For that matter, no workaround is really the right thing to do, but it is usually all that can be done until there *is* a right thing to do. If the SE developers would give us some sort of centering, whether limited to images or more general, we could do the right thing. Just for the record, I despise the use of `${}{}{}{}{}$` just to get around the minimum comment length.

Comment: @ArthurFischer: However, from [What is MathJax?](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/mathjax.html):  "It was designed with the goal of consolidating the recent advances in web technologies into a single, definitive, math-on-the-web platform supporting the major browsers and operating systems, including those on mobile devices." It is not clear that MathJax was intended only to format equations. Since images are definitely part of mathematical exposition, I'd think that MathJax would support some image display if it really wants to be "a single, definitive, math-on-the-web platform".

Comment: @robjohn I don't buy the "semantic" argument. I just wanna know if it works. quid said it doesn't, but 2 other people said it does. Maybe quid can't see the image because the image itself is too wide, not because it has whitespace on the left.

Comment: @Wood: I am not making a judgement, just repeating what quid said was the reason it was wrong to use MathJax for spacing. I have no idea what the posts look like on others' mobile devices. I do know that there was some change recently; I used to be able to scroll horizontally on my iPhone to see things wider than its screen, but now the page is truncated. I don't know if that is a change to my browser or to SE.

Comment: @quid: I am tickling the CMs here about this situation to see if we can get the old [feature-request](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2851) resolved. Then perhaps we can do the right thing.

Comment: @Wood I mentioned that the image is outside the screen  for the example using  &nbsp; Indeed, in this respect the MJ-trick is better, which is why I replied to you that "In some ways &nbsp; is better in some ways it is worse." But there are other MJ formatting cludges that do mess up the mobile view. This one is not one of them, and I did not claim it was (though a formulation might have been  prone to misunderstanding); the ojection was a different one. // robjohn: that's a good idea!

Comment: Since my comments have been bandied about, here, I thought I would respond with a little clarification.  First, my comment to quid was not a private one, but a public one [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/17496/would-html-unicode-formatting-cause-troubles/17543#17543).  Second, in terms of semantics, this is not just an abstract idea of good practice but one that actually affects people.  As described in the link I just gave, one important group of users who are affected by this is those using screen readers (and that includes not just blind, but also dyslexic ...

Comment: ... and other users with special needs).  Having things visually correct but semantically broken will make their (already hard) experience harder.  Marking something as mathematics that is really only there for spacing can cause confusion, as they will hear a math section that has not math content.  My own feeling is that minor improvement in visual aesthetics is outweighed by the detrimental affect it has on the non-visual uses of the page.

Comment: @DavideCervone: Thank you; what you say makes very good sense. Had I considered that the site would be used by the visually impaired, I would have filled in the "enter image description here" portion of the images as well. As it is, I am very unfriendly and I apologize.

Comment: @robjohn, I have only become alert to the needs of those who use assistive technology recently myself, and have made lots of mistakes in this area in my own past.  I'm trying to do better moving forward, and encourage the users of MSE to take those kinds of needs into account in discussions such as this.  I appreciate your positive response.

Comment: @robjohn, since you said the MathJax website wasn't clear about it, let me say that MathJax currently is intended only to format equations; other layout is expected to be done via HTML.  (MathJax's internals allow for non-math content, but so far no component uses that.)  In terms of images, Math is frequently used as labels in images, but images in equations are much rarer (though still done).  MathJax does supper the `<mglyph>` MathML element for this, but there is no built-in means of accessing it from TeX.  There is a 3rd-party extension for it, however.

Comment: Finally, `\hskip` is not a text-only macro.  The `\mskip` macro only takes arguments in units of `mu` (math units, which are relative the to current font size).  Page 168 of the TeXbook explicitly says "`\hskip` and `\kern` (which are allowed in formulas) must never give units in `mu`".  So `\hskip` is also a math-mode macro, which is why MathJax implements it.

Comment: @DavideCervone: thank you for the clarification. I guess the sources I was using were not as explicit and so I was unclear on these points.

Comment: @DavideCervone: I have added a section regarding your comments. Let me know if I have anything that needs changing.

Comment: @robjohn, that looks good.  Centering is something HTML is good at, and a centering mode in SE markdown would be an excellent addition.

Comment: @DavideCervone: Yes. Simply allowing `<center>...</center>` would be adequate.

Comment: @quid: Until we have a consensus on the site, we probably shouldn't go editing posts just to remove `\hspace` and `\hskip`. Once we have a real centering solution, these commands will let us know where centering was intended (should it be an option rather than applied to all images). In new posts or posts that need to be edited for other reasons, I suggest that we don't pseudo-center, but in the image description, we add "(to be centered)" so that we know where centering should be applied when we have it.

Comment: @robjohn this seems reasonable to me. One could also record the information that it should be centered as a html-comment.

Comment: @quid: true, but the fewer patterns we need to search for to find images to center properly, the easier the task will be. If we suggest one or two to the community, most will use one of those suggestions.